# Animations in figma using dropdown

Tags: animation, dropdown, figma

I'm starting to learn how to make animations in figma and I'm having a problem.

I created a dropdown and I need an information text to appear next to or below the dropdown every time I change options.

Could you help me please?

I created a dropdown and I need an information text to appear next to or below the dropdown every time I change options.

Could you help me please?

Comment: you'll need to use Auto Layout.